SQL Server built-in functions in H2
I'm working on a Spring Data JPA application that connects to SQL Server and uses H2 for integration testing (JUnit). I have a native SQL query that uses the SQL Server DATENAME function, like this:
CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, datetime) = 'Sunday' THEN …

The issue is that DATENAME doesn’t exist in H2. H2 has similar functions like DAYNAME, but they are not available in SQL Server. This makes it difficult to write a SQL query that works for both the application and the unit tests.
Do you have any suggestions?
P.S. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Created a custom function in H2 called DATENAME. This works if the first parameter is a string literal:
DATENAME('dw', datetime)

However, rewriting the SQL query this way causes it to stop working on SQL Server.

Created a function in SQL Server called DAYNAME:
CREATE FUNCTION DAYNAME(@dateValue DATETIME2)
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATENAME(dw, @dateValue)
END

This approach seemed promising because H2 has a built-in DAYNAME function. However, it doesn’t work because in SQL Server, you need to prefix it with dbo, like this:
dbo.DAYNAME(datetime)

And this doesn’t work with H2.


Any ideas would be appreciated!
Thanks!

application that connects to MS SQL Server and uses H2 for unit testing ... don't use 2 very different databases for testing and development, otherwise you get this sort of problem.  In any case, rightfully your unit tests should not be calling the database anyway, so they should be working regardless.
